# brew install lua@5.1: "No available formula for the name "Lua@5.1""

Tags: macos, installation, lua, homebrew

Installing `Lua@5.1` using `brew install lua@5.1` (as stated in the website)
https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/lua@5.1
Results in an error for me on macOs terminal.

```
brew install lua@5.1
Warning: No available formula with the name "lua@5.1".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I have used brew update, and I have reinstalled brew, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Solved by reinstalling core utilities

Comment: what do you mean by "core utilities"?

Comment: @chenrui brew install coreutils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

brew install coreutils fixed it for me